# How do I turn off this Eslint error "Expected new line break before and after html tags"?

Tags: eslint, prettier

I am using nuxt JS and everytime I run 'npm run dev', I get this error:

```
       7:40  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<v-card-title>`), but no line breaks found    vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline
      17:81  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</v-card-title>`), but no line breaks found  vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline
      20:14  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<p>`), but no line breaks found               vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      23:12  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<a>`), but no line breaks found               vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      23:25  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</a>`), but no line breaks found             vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      23:30  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</p>`), but no line breaks found             vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      24:14  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<p>`), but no line breaks found               vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      28:12  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<a>`), but no line breaks found               vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      28:19  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</a>`), but no line breaks found             vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      28:24  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</p>`), but no line breaks found             vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      29:14  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<p>`), but no line breaks found               vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      33:12  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<a>`), but no line breaks found               vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      33:23  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</a>`), but no line breaks found             vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      33:28  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</p>`), but no line breaks found             vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      42:12  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<a>`), but no line breaks found               vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      42:30  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</a>`), but no line breaks found             vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      47:12  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<a>`), but no line breaks found               vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      47:23  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</a>`), but no line breaks found             vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      56:12  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<v-btn>`), but no line breaks found           vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
      56:20  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</v-btn>`), but no line breaks found         vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline
```

How do I turn off this error?

Comment: Are you using VS Code? If so you need to turn off that rule check in VS Code settings for linting.

Comment: I'm using WebStorm.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, Fixed the problem. The error was because of

> eslint-plugin-vue

So, I added following code in my eslintrc.js file

```
'vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline': 'off',
'vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline': 'off',
```

Answer (score 1):

This warning says that you should avoid single line tags. For example, instead of

`<nuxt-link to="/test">Another page</nuxt-link>`

just use this:

```
<nuxt-link to="/test">
  Another page
</nuxt-link>
```